# Why ferroelectricity requires empty $d$-orbitals?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, orbitals

I understand that ferroelectricity needs off-centre cations, but why it requires the cation to be empty or fully filled *d*-orbits?

Ref: Multiferroicity in atomic van der Waals heterostructures
Nature Communications 10, 2657 (2019)